# Part of my code fails to exeecute

Tags: java, io

The purpose of this program is to:

1.Ask a user to enter a URL

2.To check whether the URL is correct

3.To create  a file

4.To send the URL to the file.

Its basically that simple

But the program terminates at step3 without carrying out step 4

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    System.out.println("Hello there user!" );
    System.out.println("What's your name?");

    Scanner name=new Scanner (System.in);
    String namelocation=name.nextLine();
    //We will later want to impress the user by calling them by their names
    System.out.println("What name would you like to give your file? Remember to keep no spaces between the letters or words");
    Scanner filename=new Scanner (System.in);
    String systemfilename=filename.nextLine();
    //We are creating a file to store  the name of the user and the browser


    try {

          File file = new File(systemfilename);

          if (file.createNewFile()){
            System.out.println("The file has been successfully created!");
          }else{
            System.out.println("File already exists.");
          }

        } catch (IOException e) {
          e.printStackTrace();}


    System.out.println("hello" +namelocation+ "now enter the URLS of the browsers");

    Scanner weblink=new Scanner(System.in);
    String webpath=weblink.nextLine();
    //From here we want to find out if the normal format of writing URLS has been followed e.g does it begin with https:, and .com

    int numberofcharacters=webpath.length();//we will use this later on to get the final position of the last substring

    String linklength=webpath.substring(0,7);
    if (linklength.equals("https:")){
        System.out.println("Good so far");
    }
    String linklength1=webpath.substring(0,4);
    if(linklength1.equals("www.")){
        System.out.println("Good so far");
    }
    else{
        System.out.println("Incorrect link!!!");
    }
    //Now we are getting the position of the last substring
    int linklength2=numberofcharacters-4;
    int linklength3=numberofcharacters+1;

    String linklength4=webpath.substring(linklength2,linklength3);
    if(linklength4.equals(".com")){
    System.out.println("Great!!!");
    }
    if(linklength4.equals(".edu")){
        System.out.println("Great!!!");
    }
    if(linklength4.equals(".gov")){
    }
    else{
        System.out.println("Something might not be right with this link");

    }
    String content = webpath;
    PrintStream out = null;
    //this is where we print the URL to the file
    try {
        out = new PrintStream(new FileOutputStream(content));
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }
    System.setOut(out);




    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}
```

}
}

Comment: In your try/catch statement: Does your catch have a closing parenthesis or did you copy/paste your code here wrong? From the code you have put here it looks like all of the bottom section of your code is in your catch statement... That would explain why nothing in the bottom half is running.

Comment: What exactly do you mean?

Comment: The Catch statement should look like: 
`} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}` <-- does it have this parenthesis? Just making sure.

Comment: Is there something wrong with `Console.WriteLine();`?

Comment: Yes it does, actually even if I did forget to put the paranthesis the IDE would have corrected it anyway

Comment: What do you mean "wrong with Console.WriteLine();"  It looks okay

Comment: Alright just making sure. Could you edit your code above to include the closing parenthesis in that case?

Comment: I've edited it.What exactly is the problem?

Comment: Yow, I've been calling it a parenthesis this whole time... I mean bracket. See my answer, I'm pretty sure you aren't closing the catch statement right.

Answer (score 0):

You are not properly closing your catch statement. A try/catch block needs to be in this format:

```
try {
// stuff to try
} catch {
// do stuff in this case
}
```

Your try/catch block is missing the closing bracket in the catch block. You have:

```
 } catch (IOException e) {
          e.printStackTrace();
```

Side note: an opening bracket is this --> `{` a closing bracket is this --> `}`. Whenever you use an opening bracket be mindful of where your closing bracket goes.

Because you never close your catch block everything below it is included in the catch block. Meaning... the only way the url checker code will run is if the file creation fails...

Change your catch block to this:

```
} catch (IOException e) {
         e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Your IDE is not throwing an error about it most likely because you have just added an extra closing bracket to the very end of your code. I assume that' what the double brackets at the very end of your post is.

Comment: Thanks man! I didn't know that was the problem.Next time I'll be more carefull with those "try catch" statements.

Comment: I'm guessing what happened is you saw the IDE highlighting the last bracket of the class in red and just added one more down there to get rid of the error. If the last bracket is ever highlighted red it almost always means you have incorrectly closed a statement somewhere else in the code. It happens.

Comment: Make sure to mark this as an answer if it worked for you. And, you might want to get rid of the closing bracket on the catch block in the code you put up there so my answer is a little easier to understand.